# Bootstrap validator file name required does not fail validation when it should

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrapvalidator

I am using the validator plug-in to validate my form. I have a simple form with a single input box with type=file.

I have set up a rule which I believe sets the form field to required. When the form loads, and I click on the Submit button without entering a file name or browsing to a file, the form gets validated.

I need the form to fail validation and generate an error message stating that a file needs to be selected.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```html
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="test_file_upload.aspx.vb" Inherits="ARDirectWithMobile.test_file_upload" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title id="titleTag"><%: Page.Title %> 401(k) Account</title>
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
    <link runat="server" id="StyleLink1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrapValidator.min.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="contactForm" runat="server" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">File Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-6 bs-example">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="uploadfile" />
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Navigate to the file you wish to upload" CssClass="label_under_text"></asp:Label> 
     </div>                          
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#contactForm').bootstrapValidator({
                container: '#messages',
                feedbackIcons: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                rules: {
                    uploadfile: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                fields: {
                    uploadfile: {
                        validators: {
                            file: {
                                extension: 'txt,xls,csv',
                                message: 'You must select a valid payroll file to upload'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you don't need the `rule`

```
rules: {
    uploadfile: {
        required: true
    }
},
```

Second, you have to set `notEmpty` so bootstrapValidator check the file input

```
notEmpty: {
  message: 'You must select a valid payroll file to upload'
},
```

Third you have to set the `type` for `extensions`, in your case file extensions are `'txt,xls,csv',` , also I think `csv` not supported, you may need custom validation rule for it. (see the edit at the bottom)

[BootstrapValidator Supported file formats](http://bootstrapvalidator.votintsev.ru/validators/file/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#contactForm').bootstrapValidator({
      container: '#messages',
      feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
      },
      fields: {
        uploadfile: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'You must select a valid payroll file to upload'
            },
            file: {
              extension: 'txt,xls,csv',
              type: 'text/plain,application/vnd.ms-excel,text/csv'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
});
```

**Edit:** you can validate `csv` extension as type `text/csv' without custom validation.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltuq9v67/2/)

Comment: I copied and pasted your modified script but there was no change in my results.  The form still validates when I click on the Submit button without specifying a file name.  It does fail validation if I click on "Choose File" and select a file other than the accepted file types so that's good.  Any other ideas?

Comment: try remove `container: '#messages',` from script

Comment: checked with container: '#messages', http://jsfiddle.net/Ltuq9v67/3/ and it's working, you need to check the browser console log for error, see anything is there

Comment: side note: use latest version of bootstrapValidator, you can get it from here https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-validator

Comment: removing the container worked!  Thank you for your time and assistance!

Comment: you are welcome, don't forget to mark the answer correct. :)

Comment: I would mark the answer correct, but I dont know how to do that.

Comment: (without looking the complete code can suggest these) if the other fields are failing too check your browser console log for JS errors, you may be missing something like `,` or closing brackets which always cause the validation fail, if there is nothing is console log and you believe that JS is correct and it may be ASP issue, should open new question and sidenote: you can put your code here http://jsfiddle.net/Ltuq9v67/3/ save the fiddle and paste the link here, can check it quickly

Comment: There you go, how and why accept the answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work